# convert pixel coordinates between resolutions

Tags: javascript, svg, graphics, pixel, resolution

I make web application with svg and wonder how can I determine pixel coordinates in different resolutions.

There are a lot of answers like 'just multiply by ratio between resolutions' but when I do that pixel coordinates will not be integers so how can I determine where this pixel will exactly be?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Would scaling the application down/up with the screen resolution work?

Comment: And how to implement that kind of scaling?

Comment: use context.save(), context.scale(), and context.restore(). If you put in a few google searches you should be able to figure out how to use those functions.